# In Fluent Validation, Is there a way for copying existing rule of a property from other validator's property rule for example for foreign keys?

Tags: c#, .net-core, fluentvalidation

I am trying to control validator rules at a center. So, I don't want to write same rules for foreign key properties. For example:

**Validator for EntityA**

```
public class firstValidator : AbstractValidator<EntityA>
    {
        public firstValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(p=>p.Id).GreaterThanOrEqualTo(0);

            RuleFor(p=>p.EntityBId).//Rules For EntityBId which defined already in another code file
        }
    }
```

**Validator For EntityB**

```
public class secondValidator : AbstractValidator<EntityB>
    {
        public secondValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(p=>p.Id).// Rules for ID of EntityB is defined here I am trying to copy this rules for EntityA's EntityBId propery.

        }
    }
```

**As seen in code files**, I want to copy 'EntityB.Id' property validation rules int secondValidator class to 'EntityA.EntityBId' rules in firstValidator class. Is there any way to do that ?

**What I mean to copy, I mean if rules change at secondValidator also rules change at firstValidator.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the following link which explains how to share validation.
https://www.locktar.nl/programming/net-core/apply-same-validation-rules-on-different-classes-with-fluentvalidation/